# Querying Excel by multiple users - Need suggestion

Tags: vba, excel

I am seeking one suggestion on how to build an excel macro for below requirement. Request you to provide your valuable comments in EXCEL Only.

**Scenario**
I have one spreadsheet "Product Master" that contains all the product details.
(i.e. Product ID,Product Name,Product Type,Quantity etc etc)

I am designing a `UserForm` using excel VBA where anyone can fetch all the details of a product based on its Product ID. Now the product-master sheet where all the product details is present will get updated on a daily basis. And each user should be able to update any details in that sheet based on his requirement.

**Questions/Doubts**
How do I design my system? I mean where should I put my "Product-Master" spreadsheet so that it can be accessed by multiple users. What I am thinking is to put product-masster on a shared_drive so that all can access that sheet through VBA `userform`. I will provide excel VBA `userform` macro to everyone in my office & they will query that sheet present in shared drive. does this seem ok?

Does excel provide facility to Query data from sheet present in shared-drive & update it when required. And I want this to be queried by multiple users at a time.

I know there are other products/technologies that provides better solution than EXCEL. But I want the solution in EXCEL ONLY.

I would appreciate it if anyone can provide his/her valuable comments on this. Let me know in case you need any details.

Thanks you.

Comment: If it's an option, you may be better off putting the Product Master in  an MS Access Database table. The Access DB can be stored on the shared drive and queried by multiple users -- if you use legacy .MDB instead of .ACCDB then users do not need an MS Access license or install to query the data from Excel via the Data Access Object (you'd need to have a copy, though, to create the initial database.) If this is an option I can post an example later today.

Comment: @Karter - I need a solution in EXCEL itself. Let me know if above requirement can be handled using excel ! Thanks.

Comment: Querying can be done multiple times. But updating can be done one at a time. I set up the same system. To view it, you just open the file in readonly state. To update, you need a routine that will check if the file is open first and then decide what to do. There's a lumitation in the updating process since multiple users at once is not possible but purely excel.

Comment: The Access option is the only thing that is going to work reliably. Multiple people hitting an Excel file is going to result in a lock at some point and it's going to be harder to deal with that using a DB. You can view and manipulate the data in Excel from a user's perspective, just like normal. To the end user it would not matter if the data are stored in Access, excel a text file or whatever. All they see is it working.

Comment: All - Considering all these excel limitations in mind. Can anyone suggest me any alternative to accomplish my requirement. You can give your own suggestion or techniques. No need to stick with the method i have mentioned in my question. the only thing is i want solution in EXCEL only. Thank you.

Comment: You can keep asking, but you're going to keep getting the same response. You can spend countless hours trying to get Excel to act like Access, or you can use the correct tool for the job. Or, as an alternative, give some reasons why you think you cannot use anything other than Excel and we can suggest specific ways around those limitations. As it stands right now, you're request is too broad for this forum. StackOverflow is for getting answer to specific items, not overall product design. See the help for more details on good question asking: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here are some example functions getting data from/posting data to MS Access (took me awhile to dig these up, hah!). This uses a Reference to the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library and will only work with legacy .mdb files, not accdb (because the mdb driver is 100x faster and doesn't have a memory leak.)

```
Const DBPath As String = "Full\Database\Path"

Function GET_ACCESS_DATA(DBPath, SQL) As Object

    Dim dbConn As Object
    Dim dbRS As Object
    Dim SQL As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    SQL = "Sql Query"

    'Set up database connection string
    Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to Database..."

    'Open database connection
    Set dbConn = OpenDatabase(DBPath)

    'Run the query
    Application.StatusBar = "Running Query..."
    Set dbRS = dbConn.OpenRecordset(SQL, DAO.dbOpenForwardOnly, DAO.RecordsetOptionEnum.dbReadOnly)

    'If no rows returned, display error message and exit
     If dbRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Running Query...Error"
        MsgBox "There are no records for the selected criteria.", vbInformation, "Refresh Data"
        Application.StatusBar = "REFRESHING DATA PLEASE WAIT.."
        Exit Function
    End If

    'returns DAO Recordset with the data

    Set GET_ACCESS_DATA = dbRS

    'A recordset can either be looped through or pasted to a spreadsheet with the Worksheet.Range.CopyFromRecordset method


'Error trap here
End Function


Function POST_TO_ACCESS() As Boolean

    POST_TO_ACCESS = False

    errormod = "TRACKING"
    On Error GoTo ERROR_TRAP:

    'START CONTROLS
    Application.StatusBar = "Formatting Data"

    St_Timer = Timer 'start connection timer
    Dim cn As DAO.Database
    Set cn = DAO.OpenDatabase(DBPath)
    En_Timer = Timer 'get connection time

    'SetKey Parameters
    UserNM = Replace(User_Name(), Chr(39), "")
    CompNm = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")

    Elapsed_Time = En_Timer - St_Timer
    SQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_TRACKING " & _
            "(UserNM) " & _
            " VALUES ('" & UserNM & "')"

    cn.Execute SQL

    cn.Close


    'END CONTROLS
    Application.StatusBar = False

    POST_TO_ACCESS = True

'error trap here
End Function

Function User_Name()

'This just gets the LDAP username of whoever is logged in. Useful for tracking. Not guarenteed to work for your Active Directory :)

    Dim WshNetwork
    Dim objAdoCon, objAdoCmd, objAdoRS
    Dim objUser, objRootDSE
    Dim strDomainDN, strUserName, strUserFullName

    strUserFullName = ""

    Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    strUserName = WshNetwork.UserName

    Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
    strDomainDN = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

    Set objAdoCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objAdoCon.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

    Set objAdoCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objAdoCmd.ActiveConnection = objAdoCon

    objAdoCmd.CommandText = _
      "SELECT ADsPath FROM 'LDAP://" & strDomainDN & "' WHERE " & _
      "objectCategory='person' AND objectClass='user' AND " & _
      "sAMAccountName='" & strUserName & "'"

    Set objAdoRS = objAdoCmd.Execute

    If (Not objAdoRS.EOF) Then
      Set objUser = GetObject(objAdoRS.Fields("ADsPath").Value)
      objUser.GetInfoEx Array("displayName"), 0
      strUserFullName = objUser.Get("displayName")
      Set objUser = Nothing

      User_Name = strUserFullName

    Else

    End If

    Set objAdoRS = Nothing
    Set objAdoCmd = Nothing
    objAdoCon.Close
    Set objAdoCon = Nothing

    Set objRootDSE = Nothing
    Set WshNetwork = Nothing

End Function
```